# ActiveRecord::Persistence#reload does not reload objects unless they are accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a method that creates one or more new ActiveRecord objects and returns them as an array:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :children

  def build_children
    5.times do |i|
      Child.create
    end
    return children
  end

end
```

While writing a spec for the corner case where the user accidentally calls `build_children` twice, I noticed that it did not fail as expected:

```
# passes
it "should return the previous batch of children if build_children called twice" do
  parent = Parent.create
  children = parent.build_children
  more_children = parent.build_children
  children.should == more_children
end
```

I thought this would fail, returning an array of 5 Children in the first call, 10 in the second.  Instead, it returns the original 5 both times.

The addition of a reload does not make it fail either!  In fact, the only way it seems to fail is if I access the returned array somehow after reloading, like printing it:

```
# this fails, as expected
it "should return the previous batch of children if build_children called twice" do
  parent = Parent.create
  children = parent.build_children
  parent.reload
  puts children
  more_children = parent.build_children
  children.should == more_children
end
```

Confusing matters further, this sequence of commands works as expected in the console:

```
  parent = Parent.create
  children = parent.build_children
  parent.reload
  more_children = parent.build_children
  # => [ array of 10 children ]
```

Does `reload` behave differently inside an rspec example group?  What is so special about accessing an instantiated AR object?

Comment: How are you setting up your scores variable and your more_scores variable?

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: So it's all working now?

Comment: No, it was just a typo in my sanitized version of the code.  Any theories?

Comment: Clutching at straws, but how about `children = parent.build_children
  children += parent.build_children
  children.size.should == 10`